# const-type is not accepted as constant initializer

Tags: c, compiler-errors, constants

following (simplified) piece of code causes an

```
error C2099: initializer is not a constant
```

in last line of this snippet:

```
static const char rowmans_1_width = 16;
...
const char rowmans_width[96] = {rowmans_1_width, rowmans_2_width, rowmans_3_width,...
```

So **rowmans_1_width** is defined as "const" but compiler still complains it is not constant. This happens when I compile this as C-code, when using as C++ it works smoothly.

My Problem: I have to use a C compiler now and I can't simply use a

```
#define rowmans_1_width 16
```

because I had to change very much at very different positions - means a simple search/replace would not work. So, any ideas how I can overcome this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You could do `enum { rowmans_1_width = 16 };` if your constants are integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right, unlike C++, `const` variables in C are not *constant expressions*.

I don't think there is a portable way other than using the preprocessor:

```
#define rowmans_1_width 16
```